# Running a java file from grunt, doesnt open Port for Browserstack

Tags: gruntjs, browserstack

I am running the `BrowserStackTunnel.jar` by the grunt plugin `grunt-exec`

(Have been using node's child_process.exec, but same results)

with the command `java -jar BrowserStackTunnel.jar -force APIKEY localhost,8000,false`

What the Java file actualy does is connecting via ssh to an Amazon instance of Browserstack and opening a port on 45691,  the website of browserstack is polling that port on localhost where the Java application serves a small snippet containing the params passed.

If i run the command from the CLI it works fine and i see the port beeing open on netstat. In the browserstack website i get the success screen.

But if i run the command from grunt-exec it shows only the `SYN` request.

The output to the command line is the same, both show success

I am not so sure what is causing this. I am running on windows7, node v0.10.12, grunt-cli v0.1.9, grunt v0.4.1 and grunt exec v0.4.2

Any idea what is causing this or how to debug it? I thought about a permission problem, but i am kind of clueless

Comment: Are you sure that you are using grunt version 1.9? The newest is version 0.4.2

Comment: it says grunt exec v0.4.2, its the grunt cli which is v0.1.9, i will add cli in the question

Comment: But `grunt-exec` is a plugin, and `grunt-cli` is just the cli, what version of `grunt` are you running in the project, the newest version is also `0.4.2` so that might course some confusion?

Comment: well as said above it is grunt 0.4.1

Comment: Possibly try to replace grunt-exec with grunt-shell. That is a more used task for running shell commands. At least worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I realized, better if I use the BrowserStackLocal binary files for creating a tunel. I solved a quite complex configuration here: [Ember.js - CircleCI - BrowserStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073949/emberjs-qunit-testem-circleci-browserstack-how-could-they-work-togethe)

BrowserStackLocal files are here: http://www.browserstack.com/local-testing (Binaries)

Comment: the only downside is see is that it is only linux 64bit, but its okay for us since we do have our CI server on linux

Comment: There is 4 version of this binary: OS X (Lion, Mountain Lion, Mavericks), Linux 32-bit, Linux 64-bit,
Windows. So, if you need 32 bit version, or would like to play on your mac or windows machine, could work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Browserstack Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browserstack-local/mfiddfehmfdojjfdpfngagldgaaafcfo?hl=en)? It was launched this january and allows you to test local files without running the cli tunnel.

Comment: this is more for a CI server, so automated testing

Answer (score -2):

As soon as the child process is created, grunt moves on to the next command. If there is nothing, the grunt process terminates and takes the child with it.

Try adding a grunt-contrib-watch task after the grunt-exec call. It should keep the grunt process alive, and the child process with it.

Comment: who said the process terminates? it is running